# Why is ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.ComboBox configured with a number of W's?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, add-in, combo-box

I'm using a `ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.ComboBox`. I configure the size of the combobox in `config.esriaddinx` with the following xml:

```
    <ComboBox id="my_id"
              class="MyComboBox"
              message="Everything is awesome!"
              caption="Everything is awesome!"
              tip="Everything is awesome!"
              category="Add-In Controls" 
              sizeString =     "WWWWWWWWWWWWW" 
              itemSizeString = "WWWWWWWWWWWWW" />
```

It work fine, but it really baffles me that the width is configured with a bunch of '`W`'s.

Can anyone explain the reasoning behind it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just conjecture, but there is probably some variable-width text measurement logic going on behind the scenes, and the character W was probably chosen because it is one of the [widest characters available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3949453/386205) in variable-width fonts. I agree that it is a bit nonsensical to do it this way.

Comment: I think this is the closest we'll get to an answer. Would be wonderful with some esri insider knowledge to shed light on the reasoning behind.

Answer (score 2):

That string represent the maximum length of string that you can show on that combo-box.That mean  if it shows "WWW" you can add items of maximum 3 character.If you entered otherwise the arc-map split that string by the maximum length and balance will shown as next item.This also mentioned in Add-in _wizard. See image below
[image: addin-wizard]

Comment: This is not (entirely) correct. I use 12 `W`s which still shows all of my longest element of about 20 chars. And it does not answer the question about the 'why'? Is there some standard where `W` is a magic representation of string length? I would this to make sense.

Comment: i have tested that also.You have enter string in to "item size string" text-box to restrict the number of characters in the item."W" is just a representation of width. But you can enter any character to that text-box.Number of the string is that only matters..

Comment: That is not entirely correct either. The size of the combobox is not the same when I use `sizeString="aaaa"` in stead of `sizeString="WWWW"` for instance. Maybe this question can really only be answered by esri. I makes no sense to me at least.

Comment: yeah that's right.

Answer (score 1):

As stated previously, this defines the width of the drop-down box, as shown [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//014p00000024000000) in the ESRI help.  This doesn't have to be a 'W'.  You can use any repeated character.  It does bring up the question of why not just use a numeric value where the number is equivalent to the width value in some predefined units.